# Getting body content sent using socket php using ports

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, port

I have code below that accepts connection using sockets and displays it, then sends back a few headers, I however cannot see the body content that has been sent to the listener, I only get the headers as indicated below the code, with the Content-length clearly indicating that content has been sent, please help

```
    $host = "192.168.8.121";
    $port = 454;

    // don't timeout!
    set_time_limit(0);

    // create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
    $result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

    do {
       $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");

    // read client input
       $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");

       $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
       $body = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); 
       print_r($input);
       print_r($body);
       print_r($inputJSON);

    // set inital headers
       $headers = [];
       $headers['Date'] = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T');
       $headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
       $headers['Server'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

       $lines = [];
       $lines[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";

       // add the headers
       foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
           $lines[] = $key . ": " . $value;
       }

       socket_write($spawn, implode("\r\n", $lines) . "\r\n\r\n" . $body) or die("Could not write output\n");
       socket_close($spawn);
    } while (true);

    // close sockets
    socket_close($socket);
```

I tried a different ways to print out the content, but I have only been able to print out the headers, this is what I get when printing the $input variable

```
     POST /test HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json, application/xml, 
     text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml User-Agent: 
     RestSharp/105.2.3.0 Content-Type: application/json Host: 
     192.168.8.102:454 Content-Length: 779 Accept-Encoding: gzip, 
     deflate
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP sends data in packets and reassembles them back into a stream. This means while you can read data byte by byte without caring for the correct order of the packets arriving at the receiver, it can still happen that one call to `socket_read()` only returns the content of one IP packet. The sender probably sends the headers as one packet, and then sends the content in one or more additional packets.

What one usually does is call the receive function in a loop similar to this:

```
$readTotal = 0;
while ($readTotal < $toRead) {
  $read = socket_read(...);
  if ($read === FALSE) {
    // error, cancel operation
  }
  $readTotal += $read;
}
```

In your case, you would have to extract the amount to read from the Content-Length field, and maybe put a timeout in the loop if you can't read the number of bytes that was promised in the header.

Comment: Hi @Karsten, tried implementing this but cant seem to get it right, It seems like exhausting resources when i do as the server becomes suddenly very slow :-(